# Set bootstrap spacing for all nested items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have this snipped of HTML code:

```
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-step-backward" title="Rewind" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-play" title="Play" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-pause" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="oi oi-media-record" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
    </div>
```

I would like any item inside the outer div have an horizontal margin of `3`.
The only way I know is to add `me-3` to the class of each item (the button group and the two other buttons). But I have to remember to add this for any other item I'm going to add.

I tried to add this to the outer div, but of course it refers to the next sibling div (if any).

Is there a way to set this margin in the outer div, but to be applied to the nested elements?

Answer (score 1):

## JS Solution

Iterate over all of the outer div children, and setAttribute class `me-3` to each one:

```js
let outerDiv = document.querySelector(".btn-group")

for (let i = 0; i < outerDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
      console.log(outerDiv.childNodes[i])
      if (i % 2 == 1) {
            outerDiv.childNodes[i].setAttribute("class", "me-3");
      } 
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-step-backward" title="Rewind" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-play" title="Play" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-pause" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="oi oi-media-record" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
    </div>
```

## CSS Solution

Similar to the JS solution, use `>` to iterate over all the children of `.btn-group`:

```css
.btn-group > button {
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-step-backward" title="Rewind" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-play" title="Play" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="oi oi-media-pause" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="oi oi-media-record" title="Pause" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
    </div>
```

I personally recommend the CSS solution as you can change the margin left and right to your liking.